# Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier

one the problems from my book, states the following:

Find the Fourier Transform of:

a) $$\frac{1}{2\pi(a-jt)^2}$$

the solution for it is -> \$\omega e^{-a\omega} \mathrm{u}(\omega)\$

I know there exist a relation such that \$1/(a+jt)^2\$    is F.T of \$te^{-at}  \mathrm{u}(t)\$. what happens to the \$1/2\pi\$ part? I don't understand how they manipulate it such that they are able to use the Fourier Table they have in the book.

Comment: In your equation, is "pi" the number 3.14... or the square pulse function?

Comment: @ThePhoton If it was the square pulse function, the x² squaring would not make much sense. :)

Comment: I've made an edit to the question to add mathematical formatting and to attempt to clarify.  Please verify that the equations are what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been doing math for a long time. Though I think you've already found most of the answer.

I don't remember all the Fourier tables but if what you say is correct, then if you suppose that ω = 2πf you finally have your solution.

\$2πf e^{-2πfa} \mathrm{u}(f)\$ which is \$\omega e^{-\omega a} \mathrm{u}(\omega)\$